# It's a good thing - talking about future or opinion

Tags: sentence-construction, clauses

From the dictionary, I know that *It's a good thing* is used when something happened, it is lucky that it happened.

But in the following sentence, that is not describing something has happened and instead it is just about a future situation or an opinion. So I think it is inappropriate to use this clause - It's a good thing.

If just saying *It's good* seems not correct, then what should be used here?

> It is a good thing that if grandparents can contribute their efforts to care for their grandchildren.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`It will be good, if grandparents can contribute their efforts ...`

You use *can* which represents the future tense. 
If you were to (more politely so) use *could* instead, then the sentence would be like

`It would be great, if grandparents could contribute their efforts...`

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELL! Can you please expand your answer to include the detail of **why** you think this is the answer and what references you used?